# GWT code is executing in interpretating level

Tags: java, gwt, extjs

My code which I have written in below is executing in interpretation level. Could anyone help me in understanding why.

```
u.getWriteToken(new ReadyStateChangeHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onReadyStateChange(XMLHttpRequest xhr) {
            try {
                if (xhr.getReadyState() == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    System.out.println("write status : "+xhr.getStatus());
                    if (xhr.getStatus() == 200) {
                        Result writeTokenResult = CustomJSONParser.parseResult(xhr.getResponseText());

                        /* logic */

                        System.out.println("inside : "+writeAccess);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // log here
                System.out.println("write exception : " + e);
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("outside : "+writeAccess);
```

The output is shown in below.

```
 .....
outside : null
.....
.....
.....
write status : 200
inside : false
```

Actual output should be something like this

```
write status : 200
inside : false
outside : null
```

Comment: Unable to get your question. Can you make it clear, what you mean by interpretation level ? Are you looking for the gwt compiler style info pretty/detailed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the output is not expected, well actually it is.
The `outside` line is printed first, because the `inside` line is part of the callback method that is executed asynchronously, after a roundtrip to the server. You should read this as 'invoke `getWriteToken` on the server, and when it's ready invoke the `onReadyChange` method on the client'. This callback will be asynchronous, i.e. the other statements after the getWriteToken will certainly be invoked before the callback happens. Hence first `outside` line is printed, and at a later time the assignment of writeaccess and `inside` output are done.

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct but can you give me in one example please.

Comment: Well the problem is that `writeAccess` is only initialized once the `onReadyStateChange` method is invoked. Since your `println outside` happens before that, it still sees the uninitialized value (`null`). Not sure what example you need.

Comment: [You should read this as 'invoke getWriteToken on the server, and when it's ready invoke the onReadyChange method on the client] - you told we need invoke getWriteToken() when it is ready. But how would we know that it is ready. Please help how can we execute the getWriteToken() first after that my S.O.P statements should be executed.

Comment: Hi Geert, Can you please help me in this. I couldn't understand how to resolve this asynchronous call.

Comment: The asynchronous call is already taking place in your code. But because it is asynchronous, you can't use the value of `writeAccess` except INSIDE the method `onReadyStateChange`. The place OUTSIDE where you are using it, will always be `null`. Perhaps you should read up a bit on async communication in Javascript. For instance here: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after converting that to synchronous call